# Behavior of bean by dynamic proxy in spring AOP

Tags: java, spring-aop

The multiple inheritance is not possible in JAVA but we can achieve it using *Introduction* advice in Spring AOP. Now question is how Spring perform dynamic implementation of multiple classes using **dynamic proxy**

Answer (score 0):

Uses the classical approach, interface inheritance and composition:

```
public interface Foo {
    void foo();
}

public class SomeFoo implements Foo {
    public void foo() {}
}

public interface Bar {
   void bar();
}

public class SomeBar implements Bar {
   public void bar() {}
}

public class SomeFooBar extends SomeFoo implements Bar {
   private Bar bar;

   public SomeFooBar(Bar bar) {
       this.bar = bar;
   }

   public void bar() {
     bar.bar();
  }

}
```